# Comprehensible Chaining of Mixins for a TypeScript Class without nesting

Tags: typescript, inheritance, typescript-typings, mixins

Recently I have come across `Mixins` in TypeScript as a way of "extending" multiple classes. However, using multiple `Mixins` could result in fairly unreadable nested `Mixin` functions:

```
class Dog extends Domesticated(Barking(PackHunting(Carnivore(FourLegged(Animal))))) {}
```

Now while this offers some *flexibility* and *specificity*, for example `PackHunting` being exclusive to `Carivore` classes, the amount of brackets does not make for *clean* and *readable* code. Quite often I don't need the *order-specificity* anyways and just need all my `Mixins` to inherit from the same *Base class*.

What I did was creating a Mixin function, that chains all the `Mixins` together, reducing the brackets to just one pair:

```
function mixin<T extends Constructor, M extends MixinFunction<T, any>[]>(
  Base: T,
  ...mixins: M
): MixinReturnValue<M> {
  return mixins.reduce((mix, applyMixin) => applyMixin(mix), Base) as MixinReturnValue<M>;
}
```

Using the helper types:

```
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;
type MixinFunction<T extends Constructor = Constructor, R extends T = T & Constructor> = (Base: T) => R;
type UnionToIntersection<T> = (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends (x: infer R) => any ? R : never;
type MixinReturnValue<T extends MixinFunction<any, any>[]> = UnionToIntersection<
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends MixinFunction<any, infer U> ? U : never }[number]
>;
```

This simplifies the `Dog` class to

```
class Dog extends mixin(Animal, FourLegged, Carnivore, PackHunting, Barking, Domesticated) {}
```

With all of the mixed in classes required to extending the base class `Animal`, e.g.:

```
function Barking<TBase extends Constructor<Animal>>(Base: TBase) {
  return class Barking extends Base {
    public bark() { console.log('woof'); }
  };
}
```

---

The question implied by this post is more of a review request: **Is this a sensible approach or did I miss something major in my testing?** In Particular, I'm not overly happy with the use of the `UnionToIntersection` hack that calculates the correct return type for the `Mixin` function.

I did find [this article](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know-part-2/) going deeper into chaining mixins which depend on each other in a specific order. But for my current setup I don't really require order-dependent mixins.

---

Link to a playground containing some of the tests I did: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqUAvFAN4C+AfCVAhAO5QAUAdOwIaoDmSAXFA4IQAbQC6AShI0CAbgBQoSFACyASwAeahADF0CbGsSEoEDcAgIAJkliIUGbLlrxkaLDlQAaKACVT5pY2UESkRABkdm6OnjSkzABCHEgQAgRSxDS+CkrQAKoIRggEcACSCBaoKYbGBHEsRGYW1rZCIFAA-CwaaRk0bVAC9ABuEKhSTUG2zD1Q2gBmY359gsKdfoN0EKOoOeDQ6loIvhDA6KgIAGocADboECaTLaqa2noGwEV4bT5tVOL1ApFErlSrVT7GeRQchQEQAaTmCCgAGsICA4PMQmI0vCxAFmsFDm99DUEN9hD4Fks8jQunlNiMlhQRAh0ABbABGYzE8ioCnk8xJEKRbNeZMagWergcHlwPhU+KmLyO71JhF+wn+YioiWSqRCPnYrCJyAEKgkZrFJzOF2udweKhoZChUFQp3OSJNSFYbqsWAgzGYh3lYpWJqDmgkPiSKSkyWV2mtHrt9zwjoUFHk8kwN2StgACnAkGphRwOTdoM7oWB0OW1JgoLNWZyxgpq7WbvWoCAhuyubsXTW6w2AF69lsDwcdruYezuJyoGbj-s+Ht0PtjHxj9cTqRV6FQYAACzU3o0tA0bYPx9PrHapBAV+hN+9I9oI6vmczAqFRSgACl2TAMsK0IGNoCeYJpXnTw8ELYtS3LCAqB1cC0nAvcXTdG0kRzPMAKAkCIMlYJwPIF122HKAACsgOYPdDxPb0QAAahY2QoEzaEKAzLNBQ+P8AHVbmRIiwL1RUpTnGJcDgosSyKIiUN1FJ0L1TDoWwj0oDwpBbGEm5RKQyTSIk-dKM7BsGBEnRcGs1ArGYFAIDAfgd37BiX1Yc8WNIZzXI4riDyHSyoGswykkwZF7Mc-y3ObDyYS888AFo-IsALOJdHj5G-XTbF8OAOTgYATNsUUjmYeCFMQIifEAtlgKQnwDKMitMIASBCrsEA4Nl9QcbRuH5LrpwbWdollRdev6gRBoQbhDXYMB5OFAQWQ3bx3M3bbUEkciOo6pB0EgRcjRWhCigkBRDq8mboFIe6bq-LMJpQV0ipK2h6CYQriuAZgAHI-TZNkQEBnwAAYoah675FQT7gFYcLkVs1AYuYABGSG4YR-7WFoxr6NkIA)

---

## Update

In case anyone is interested, I threw together a small package containing the approach outlined here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mixin-extended.
It does have some extra-smarts, such as `MixinINstance` (`InstanceType` for `mixin` functions), but is otherwise more or less the same.

Comment: any update on your findings?

Comment: Nope, although I haven't heavily used mixins for a while. I'll have a look if some new TS feature may have popped up since then as soon as I find the time. I have not exported the `UnionToIntersection` type, so I don't have to look at it too often - and that's been working fine for me

Comment: @NateMay I have thrown together an npm package if you are interested: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mixin-extended